# How do I convert datetime to a different format? [perl]

Tags: perl, datetime

Need help parsing the datetime stamp and splitting it up by date and time.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $string = "05:57:03 08/31/10 MDT";

print $string,"\n";

my $time = Time::Piece->strptime($string, "%H:%M:%S");
my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($string, "%Y/%m/%d");

print $time,$date,"\n";
```

Thanks! **Also how do I figure out which day of week this is using code?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use code like the following:

```
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($string, "%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%y %Z");
```

However, on my system at least, I have to change the time zone MST to GMT for it to match; if I leave it as in your example, I get an error:

```
Perl> my $t = Time::Piece->strptime("05:57:03 08/31/10 DST", "%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%y %Z");
[!] Runtime error: Error parsing time at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0/Time/Piece.pm line 469.
```

If it works for you, though, you'll have a Time::Piece object, on which you can call e.g. `$t->day_of_week` for the day of the week as a number, `$t->day` for e.g. 'Tue', or `$t->fullday` for e.g. 'Tuesday'.

See the documentation for [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Time-Piece) for details on the methods you can call.

Comment: Thanks! Now I gotta to figure out how to get the timezone to work.

Answer (score 7):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
my $s  = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%T %D %Z');
my $dt = $s->parse_datetime('05:57:03 08/31/10 MDT');
say $dt->strftime('%A'); # Tuesday
```