# Convert Month Date Time Year format to MM-DD-YYYY format in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to convert the following date to `MM-DD-YYYY` format.

`Sep 12 00:00:00 2012` in Perl

Comment: [How do I convert datetime to a different format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054013/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-a-different-format-perl)

Answer (score 1):

For a core-module that offers both `strptime()` and `strftime()' functionality, you can use [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/Time-Piece-1.20/Piece.pm).

```
use Time::Piece;
my $date = q(Sep 12 01:02:03 2012);
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y");
print $t->strftime("%m-%d-%Y\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several modules that will do this, but `Time::Piece` is probably the best choice as it has been part of the core Perl distribution since v5.9.

This code does what you ask. Note that `%e` in the `strptime` format expects days from `1` to `31`. If the day is zero-padded to two digits then `%d` must be used instead to allow for `01` to `31`.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime('Sep 12 00:00:00 2012', '%b %e %T %Y');
print $dt->strftime('%d-%m-%Y');
```

**output**

```
12-09-2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $input_format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y',
   locale    => 'en_US',
   time_zone => 'local',
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $input_format->parse_datetime('Sep 12 00:00:00 2012');
say $dt->strftime('%m-%d-%Y');
```

Comment: @Borodin, You have no way of knowing DateTime::Format::Strptime exports nothing unless you check all versions of DateTime::Format::Strptime including those that haven't been written yet. Reverting the bug you introduced to my code..

Comment: Note that DT::F::Strptime's `%d` will accept space-prefixed, zero-prefixed and unprefixed day numbers, making it quite robust.